# Cyclic Product of the Integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I have a question about the following group:

$\mathbf{Z}_{32}\times\mathbf{Z}_{164750}$.

I am examining this group as part of a problem classifying the number of isomorphism types of abelian groups with $2^{6}3^{3}5^{5}$ elements. My question is the following: is the group $\mathbf{Z}_{32}\times\mathbf{Z}_{164750}$ cyclic? How would one prove or disprove this?

I think that I may be overthinking this because of how large of a number $164750$ is. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think you need gcd to be 1 for true, and false otherwise(2 is clearly common)

Comment: As in the group is cyclic if $gcd(32, 164750)=1$ and not cyclic otherwise?

Comment: Exactly. If gcd(m,n) = 1, then (1,1) has order mn in $Z_m \times Z_n$. Therefore the group is cyclic.

Comment: @YunusSyed In other words, the group I am examining would not be cyclic?

Comment: No, there is an obvious divisor common to both 32 and 164750. Therefore, your group is not cyclic.

Comment: @YunusSyed Thank you very much! That makes much more sense now!

Comment: Also a minor thing, I think 168750 factors to $2^6*3^3*5^5$, not $164750$ (which factors to $2*5^3*659$). It's minor and doesn't really change the answer to your question, but just in case, since you're examining groups of order $2^63^35^5$.

Comment: @yandz Thank you very much! I hadn't caught that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$ Z_m × Z_n $ is cyclic group if and only if m and n are coprime that is $gcd(m, n) = 1$.

Clearly $gcd(32, 164750) ≠ 1$ (because factor 2 is common in both).
So given group is "not" cyclic!!